# Cannot Drop Footage Into Final Cut Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, final-cut-pro

I've just bought a second-handed MacBook Pro (late 2013 - Catalina 10.15.1,) and with the deal it comes with FCP 10.4.4.

For this version, I cannot drop the footage from the Finder to the program, I also cannot import the sound effects (with built-in ) into the timeline. The warning is "not enough disk space" even though I gave FCP full disk access and there are plenty of space in my Mac.

I cannot update it because it was purchased by the previous owner. I don't want to have to purchase it again.

Comment: I'm afraid your "deal" wasn't worth the paper it wasn't printed on. You are not the owner of that software, nor even of the OS itself until you wipe the entire machine & set it up as your own. See https://support.apple.com/HT201065 The original owner should have done the first 5 steps. You need to start from step 6.

Comment: I did the 6 steps. I will interpret your comments as this problem cannot solve if I'm not buying FCPX?

Comment: Best guess is that as 10.4.7 is needed for Catalina, that will be your fix. If, once on 10.4.7 you still have the issue, then we may be able to look elsewhere for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned - you will need to free up other disk space to see if you can keep the old software running without having a license to upgrade.

Are you able to post a disk usage summary so we could help advise what you can delete or move to another disk so FCP can limp along a bit longer?

Next time you’ll know to discount the purchase price so you can fund the software you need. I don’t have any good option and know gaining experience through unmet expectations can be painful sometimes.